# How to pass to a function that takes two arguments an element from one list together with each element of another list?

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python and I need help with following.
I do have a list `a = [range(1, 50, 10)]`
and another list `b = [2, 4, 5, 8, 12, 34]`
Now, I have a function that calculates something, let's call it "SomeFunction", that takes two arguments.
I want to pass to this SomeFunction for element from list **a** each element of list **b**. So, I want values for: SomeFunction(1, 2), SomeFunction(1, 4), SomeFunction(1, 5), ..... SomeFunction(50, 2), SomeFunction(50, 4), SomeFunction(50, 5), etc.

I think it should be done somehow with for loops, but I do not know how...

Comment: Whar you have tried.

Comment: Why do you have `range` in square brackets? That will not give you a range, it will give you a single-element list.

Comment: Have a look at [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). But as pointed out by others `[range(1, 50, 10)]` will give you an one element list containing a range. What you want is `a = list(range(1, 50, 10))`. Additionally the `range(1, 50, 10)` will not result in a `50` being created which you seem to think as you want `SomeFunction(50, 2)` to be a result. Also please adhere to python naming conventions and use `snake_case` to name your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a nested `for` loop:

```
a = range(1, 50, 10)
b = [2, 4, 5, 8, 12, 34] 

for aval in a:
    for bval in b:
        print(aval, bval)  # or any other function call
```

This just goes through all values in `b` for each value in `a`. (Note that you don't want `range` inside square brackets as you have in your question, I removed those).

A more advanced version: "all pairs of values" is also known as the Cartesian product, which is provided by the `itertools` module. Thus you could write

```
from itertools import product

for aval, bval in product(a, b):
    print(aval, bval)
```

Comment: This will execute till 41 not 50 i.e. `aval` would be 1, 11, 21, 31, 41

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish you are right. But that's kind of a separate issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = range(1, 50, 10)
b = [2, 4, 5, 8, 12, 34]
for i in a:
    for n in b:
        print(SomeFunction(i, n))
```